# Equations of several straight lines (piecewise) are to be merged in a single equation

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, absolute-value

The idea of the problem exists in this website and this post may be a duplicate. I saw it a long time ago, but could not find it recently.

Say we have the following $n$ straight lines:

$$y=m_1x+c_1 \text{ when }-\infty<x<x_1$$

$$y=m_2x+c_2 \text{ when }x_1<x<x_2$$

$$y=m_3x+c_3 \text{ when }x_2<x<x_3$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\text{and so on}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$y=m_{n-1}x+c_{n-1} \text{ when }x_{n-2}<x<x_{n-1}$$

$$y=m_nx+c_n \text{ when }x_{n-1}<x<x_n$$

with $-\infty<x_1<x_2<x_3<\dots<x_n<\infty$.

---

The problem is to express these in one and only one equation. I do not remember how it looks exactly, but I am sure it involves the absolute value, something like:

$3x+2+|2x+7|+|7x-5|$, which merge $4$ straight lines. (Again, I am not sure about this exact form).

[image]

---

Using the values of $m$'s, $c$'s, and $x_j$'s, how to find that single equation, using only absolute values and coefficients of $x$'s and constant terms, and no more complications?

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!